# Comparing a string to a line in a text file and act based on it

Tags: c#

I'm trying to great a program that reads a text file to compare lines in it to user input.

Currently I got it working for the first line in the file

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] commands = File.ReadAllLines(@"commands.txt");

        if (input.ToLower().Equals(commands))
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

What I'd like for it to is read the file for a line that equals the user's input and then execute a line of code related to that line of text.

Would it be possible to make the program treat the text file as list for switch?

As in:

```
switch (input)
{
*read from file*:
}
```

Comment: Do you want to switch on each individual line or the contents as a whole?

Comment: @JamesHughes Preferably it would be: (command, code) and then the same on the next line.

Comment: could you iterate over your command array, and then switch on that? Although I think a Dictionary<string,Func<T>> might be more appropriate.

Comment: @JamesHughes Could the dictionary be made to automatically create a new entry with the data given in the text file?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to use `Reflection` to define new functions on the fly if the predicate didn't already exist. Else, if it does always exist it would be fairly trivial to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it, you have two main options: iterate over your array and then switch on each individual command or, preferably, if you have a predetermined list of commands you could use a `Dictionary<string,Func<T>>`.

The first method would look something like this:

```
foreach (string command in commands)
{
     switch (command)
     {
          case: //all your commands
     }
}
```

The second method is a bit more complex but much more elegant and much more expansible:

```
Dictionary<string,Func<T>> commandPredicates = new Dictionary<string,Func<T>>(); //Create your dictionary.
commandPredicates.Add(myCommand,myAssociatedFunctionOrLambda); //Define your predicates
foreach (string command in commands)
{
    commandPredicates[command].Invoke(args); //Execute the commands
}
```

Comment: Really having trouble wrapping my head around this. How would I implement commands using the 2nd method?

Comment: The easiest way would be to have each command relate to a method and use these as your `Func` entries. Alternatively you could use lambdas or anonymous methods

Comment: Ah, I see. I've already managed to create the wanted functionality by sending the user input to the methods that execute the relevant actions, and also compressed this to a switch list to make it more compact and remove the unnecessary steps caused by using methods for each individual command. The main purpose behind what I was trying to do was to keep all the commands outside of the actual code for the program to keep it cleaner and make it easier to add new commands by just creating a new line in the text file.

Comment: Then you'd probably just want to iterate over your command list.

Comment: I'll just ditch the text file and give all the commands one line in a switch list.
Cheers for your help anyway.